# Creating iOS-style "Zoom element to next page" transitions with CSS and JS

Tags: html, css

I am building web-apps using Ratchet, replicating the look of native APPs.

Ratchet is doing a great job at replicating the look of iOS, but there is a feature which I really miss from iOS which is the ability to "move" an element to the next page by moving and zooming it.

Example: I have a list of articles. Upon clicking the thumbnail of the article, the thumbnail image gets bigger as the articles open, in a seamless transition.

The following gif. from Facebook "paper" illustrates well the effect I want to achieve:
http://d24njcbunk2gp2.cloudfront.net/assets/2014/02/Facebook-Paper-008.gif

My questions would be:
- Is this type of transition possible using only web-technologies?
- Is it possible, in general, to have one element moving in a continuous way from one page to another without any flickering effect? 
- Would such effect be possible only with single-page applications? (say a single-page website built with angularJS)
- Would any framework / tool (PhoneGap?) be useful in achieving this result

Thanks so much.

Thomas